# ExportMenu Kartik doesn't work in yii2 GridView widget

Tags: yii2

The export dropdown and toggle dropdown do not appear on click. I can't see any errors in console of developer tool.

I have used exactly same code in another project and that seems to work, the only difference is in the column set.

```
 <?php
        $exportColumns=[
            'name',
            'email',
            'username',
        ];


    echo  ExportMenu::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' =>$exportColumns,
        'dropdownOptions' => [
            'label' => 'Export All',
            'class' => 'btn btn-secondary'
        ]
    ]);
    ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding `"asDropdown" => true`

Comment: tried, didn't work

Comment: I've just tried to reproduce but both dropdown's are working fine for me. Must be a problem with the install, try running composer update/remove folder from vendor and re-install. Also make sure there are no `form` tags or anything like that wrapping the widget

Comment: I just found something, when dropdown opens it adds a class 'open' to btn-group and sets toggle as true, this is not happen when I add class via jquery myself, it seems to works fine so it's the matter of css not being added properly probably because of JS

Comment: What bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: I am using boostrap 3

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my own Yii2 project. In my project the dropdown menu worked, but the buttons that appeared were unresponsive and the entire page froze without any console error.

My own mistake was that I required two bootstrap versions in my composer.json (I left in yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap in my case, removed the other).

[Double Bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a99FN.png)